# how to point jupyter-notebook to anaconda ased python3 instead of python 2.7 which is installed earlier(not anaconda based)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebook is installed with anaconda but I had a python 2.7 on my windows machine.
**jupyter kernelspec list command is showing following result

```
Available kernels:
  python3    D:\anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3**
```

but when I use
import pandas as pd command I get the following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     17 if missing_dependencies:
     18     raise ImportError(
---> 19         "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
     20 del hard_dependencies, dependency, missing_dependencies
     21 
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

My question is why jupyter notebook is pointing to python2.7 instead on anaconda based python3. How to change it to point to python3?

Comment: Are you sure the path environment is set correctly?

Comment: I am sure that the jupyter notebook is using python2.7 but I want to use python 3 which installed with anaconda based distribution